# Facebook Graph API me/accounts return empty data & posting me/feed return error #200

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hello i try to post something on my facebook wall (My Userprofile). I created a new Facebook account and a new App in developers.facebook.com. I found alot of solutions that dosnt works for me. As first i want try to get the data from me/accounts but this return

```
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

if i try to post something on wall it return the errorcode 200

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#200) If posting to a group, requires app being installed in the group, and \
          either publish_to_groups permission with user token, or both manage_pages \
          and publish_pages permission with page token; If posting to a page, \
          requires both manage_pages and publish_pages as an admin with \
          sufficient administrative permission",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 200,
    "fbtrace_id": "HSwXSilF2Dj"
  }
}
```

I give myself every permission (using me/permissions).

What did i wrong there?

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "permission": "user_birthday",
      "status": "granted"
    },
    {
      "permission": "user_hometown",
      "status": "granted"
    },
    {
      "permission": "user_location",
      "status": "granted"
    },
    {
      "permission": "user_likes",
      "status": "granted"
    },
    {
      "permission": "user_events",
      "status": "granted"
    },
    {
      "permission": "user_photos",
      "status": "granted"
    },
    {
      "permission": "user_videos",
      "status": "granted"
    },
    {
      "permission": "user_friends",
      "status": "granted"
    },
    {
      "permission": "user_status",
      "status": "granted"
    },
    {
      "permission": "user_tagged_places",
      "status": "granted"
    },
    {
      "permission": "user_posts",
      "status": "granted"
    },
    {
      "permission": "user_gender",
      "status": "granted"
    },
    {
      "permission": "user_link",
      "status": "granted"
    },
    {
      "permission": "user_age_range",
      "status": "granted"
    },
    {
      "permission": "email",
      "status": "granted"
    },
    {
      "permission": "read_insights",
      "status": "granted"
    },
    {
      "permission": "read_audience_network_insights",
      "status": "granted"
    },
    {
      "permission": "publish_video",
      "status": "granted"
    },
    {
      "permission": "manage_pages",
      "status": "granted"
    },
    {
      "permission": "pages_manage_cta",
      "status": "granted"
    },
    {
      "permission": "pages_manage_instant_articles",
      "status": "granted"
    },
    {
      "permission": "pages_show_list",
      "status": "granted"
    },
    {
      "permission": "publish_pages",
      "status": "granted"
    },
    {
      "permission": "read_page_mailboxes",
      "status": "granted"
    },
    {
      "permission": "ads_management",
      "status": "granted"
    },
    {
      "permission": "ads_read",
      "status": "granted"
    },
    {
      "permission": "business_management",
      "status": "granted"
    },
    {
      "permission": "pages_messaging",
      "status": "granted"
    },
    {
      "permission": "pages_messaging_phone_number",
      "status": "granted"
    },
    {
      "permission": "pages_messaging_subscriptions",
      "status": "granted"
    },
    {
      "permission": "instagram_basic",
      "status": "granted"
    },
    {
      "permission": "instagram_manage_comments",
      "status": "granted"
    },
    {
      "permission": "instagram_manage_insights",
      "status": "granted"
    },
    {
      "permission": "publish_to_groups",
      "status": "granted"
    },
    {
      "permission": "groups_access_member_info",
      "status": "granted"
    },
    {
      "permission": "leads_retrieval",
      "status": "granted"
    },
    {
      "permission": "public_profile",
      "status": "granted"
    }
  ]
}
```

EDIT:

Maybe it is because i cant toggle this button? If it is true, why i cant toggle?

[Toggle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ec42q.png)

Comment: You can not post on personal user profiles any more via API.

Comment: `me/accounts` is supposed to return the _pages_ your user profile has admin rights on. Do you have any of those?

Comment: im everywhere registed as admin

Comment: that does not answer the question...do you want to post to a USER PROFILE or a PAGE?

Comment: i want to post on my user profile

Comment: in that case, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Posting to a user profile is not possible anymore, the `publish_actions` permission is deprecated.**

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes/#24-04-2018

---

Posting to a Page is still possible, and you need a Page Token with `manage_pages` and `publish_pages` for that.

More information about Tokens: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/

Comment: Thanks for information. I created a Page, there i can post some messages.